# how can I get Eclipse CDT to rebuild index with command line

Tags: eclipse

Is there anyway to use command line or any script to force Eclipse to rebuild the index of the whole workspace. I would like to make the rebuilding index be a cron job on a daily basis.

A little bit background of the context: my code base is quite big and it takes quite long to build the index. so I would like to build it every night. My platform is Fedora